# Subversion hooks problems

Tags: linux, svn, permissions, hook, svn-hooks

Spent way too much time on this one.
I created a subdomain aaa.abc.com through a Plesk Panel
I used: svn checkout svn+ssh://abc.com/var/svn/base httpdocs in the terminal
I have a post-commit hook that should update the files in my httpdocs folder.
It doesnt work , but it I use the terminal I can just use "svn update".

I do have a log and its showing an ssh error.

This hook is used to update several subdomains and they all update except this one.
I have tried every combination of permissions I could think of...
The hook is owned:-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1118 Feb 24 04:44 post-commit
The httpdocs is owned : drwxrwx---  8 svn svn 4096 Mar 11 10:05 httpdocs
My Log:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
svn: Connection closed unexpectedly
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your subversion repository and your httpdocs folder are on the same server (and it sounds like they are), you should instead use the file mechanism for checkout instead of the svn+ssh mechanism.  Using your example above, you would check out with `svn checkout file:///var/svn/base`.  Then when your post-commit hook runs it updates using the filesystem mechanism (which doesn't require ssh authentication), and everything Just Works.